# Solutions of the equation F

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Compute the solutions of the equation $F'(x)=0$, where $F: [0,\pi]  \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is given by:

$$F(x) = x + \int_{0}^{cos x} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$$

Some help for this i try first apply the FTC and then compute $F'(x)=0$ but i stuck  when apply FTC.

Comment: To apply the fundamental theorem, invoke the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FCT and chain rule gives

$$\frac {d}{dx}(\int_{0}^{\cos x} \sqrt{1-x^2} dt)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}\cdot (-\sin(x))$$

and because $0\leq x\leq \pi, \sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\sqrt{\sin^2x}$

So $F'(x)=\cdots =\cos^2x$

Comment: I prefer the OP's use of $x$ and $t$, rather than re-using the bound variable $x$ as the new unbound variable.

Comment: I copied from the op and didnt notice it was wrong, someone must have fixed it. thank you